# New Tag Proposals

Tags: discussion, tags

As I have noticed we new covering certain areas. If you think we need a perticular tag send it in with a description so it can be created after up voting. Limits one tag proposal per entry so voting can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags don't have an independent existence. Questions have tags. If you ask a question, or see a question, which would benefit from the addition of a tag which doesn't currently exist, then add it*. You don't create the tags first.

---

* If you don't have sufficient rep to add a new tag, *then* it might be appropriate to post on meta, with a link to your question, asking someone else to add the new tag for you.

Comment: I suggest using a tag, only if the tag is going to be applicable to (shared by) more than one question.

Comment: Tags which exist only on a single question are occasionally automatically deleted anyway, @ChrisW, so there's no need to worry too much about it.

Comment: "Questions *have* tags." Yes, but Tags also *have* Questions, ha ha. They co-dependently arise. "You can't have one without the other." How do I propose a new tag so I can add it to a question? If no one has created it yet, maybe it is because they cannot? Catch-22.

Comment: @nocomprende See the footnote of this answer.

Comment: @TRiG: thank you, I was able to add a tag, but not a description for it, which seems a bit awkward: how can you decide without my description? Also, I don't know where to "send proposals to", other than placing a question on Meta, which is apparently not what is wanted. Send where?

Comment: @nocomprende Meta's fine. Be specific. A tag cannot be created out of thin air: ask the question first. Then, on Meta, ask for your new tag to be attached thereto. You should be able to suggest a tag wiki through the tag interface. Failing that, post it as a question here on Meta.